# Connecting application built in Tomcat server with application built in Windows server

Tags: java, asp.net, windows, tomcat

I have an application built in **Tomcat server(Java)** and another application built in **Windows server(Dot net)**. I want to connect tomcat with windows as i *want to run both the module in one application with one database*. Please help me with

1. Process to connect

2.If there are no ways to connect, then help me with the process to convert windows server to tomcat.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown any effort what you have already tried yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the most straightforward solution would be to expose a rest API on the .net component and call this API from the tomcat component.